# Access state of a component in a test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that change some of his props when we inject different props.

I'm struggling to find a simple way to acces the state of my shallowed component from my test

Here is the code :

```
describe('componentWillReceiveProps', () => {
    it('update state isDedicatedDealPriceSelected to true', () => {
        const productComponent = shallow(<Product selectedPriceOption="Test" />);
        productComponent.setProps({ selectedPriceOption: 'dedicatedDealPrice' });
        expect(productComponent.props.isDedicatedDealPriceSelected).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I got undefined, i want to access the props isDedicatedDealPriceSelected that should be truthy. I think i'm miswritting something here on the last line in productComponent.props.isDedicatedDealPriceSelected
How can i access the props of my component ?

I'm using enzime to shallow render my component in the test with jest.

Thankd in advance !

EDIT : i was not looking to access the props, but instead the state ! sorry for the mispelling

Comment: "I have a component that change some of his props when we inject different props." I'd say this is a bad idea in general. Props is something set by parent component. Consider it immutable. Also what are you really testing? It looks like you are testing an implementation detail that has nothing to do w/ component public API: how it looks or behaves.

Comment: Sorry, the component is changing his state, not props my bad, i twisted the terms (end of the day) i want to access the state of my component. 
I tried with ```productComponent.state().isDedicatedDealPriceSelected```, and this is the answer i was looking for !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the state of a shallow rendered component, you can access it using :

```
const wrapper = shallow(<component />);
wrapper.state().componentVar
```

To access a function of a shallow rendered component, you can access it using :

```
wrapper.instance().componentFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `setProps` takes a callback executed after the re-render. Maybe your test needs to be async and the assertion to be done inside this callback.

From the examples, only `componentWillReceiveProps` seems to be called synchronously.

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html